# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError - spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to run spring boot application and getting the below error. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using java 8 to compile and spring boot 2.1.0 release.

**PFB the logs i received after running as java application.**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:282)......
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>    
            <artifactId>spring-boot-web-jsp</artifactId>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <name>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</name>
            <description>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</description>
            <url>https://www.mkyong.com</url>
            <version>1.0</version>    
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </parent>    
            <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            </properties>    
            <dependencies>    
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                    <version>4.6.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.7</version>
                </dependency>           
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
               <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
               <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>  
        </dependency> <dependency> 
                  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId> 
                  <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId> 
                  <version>1.0.32</version> 
                  <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
              </dependency> 
             <dependency>
                     <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
                     <version>1.5.3</version>
                </dependency>           
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.22</version>
                </dependency><dependency>
                     <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                     <version>2.3</version>
                </dependency> <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </dependency>  <dependency>
            <groupId>apache-oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta-oro</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency><dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency><dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency> <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jorphan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ogce</groupId>
            <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_components</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>    
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
             <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>  
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-releases</id>
                <name>Spring Releases</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
```

I'm using eclipse oxygen ide to run it. I'm using java 8 to compile and spring boot 2.1.0 release.

Comment: Can you please use 2.0.2.RELEASE version with java8?

Comment: Have you added spring context dependency?

Comment: Tried both. Didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is fixed after cleaning the builds and classpath.